# How to get values from mixed type json?

Tags: java, android, json

I have string in JSON format. For example:

```
{
   "blockedStatus":true,
   "cars":[
      "RAW:123",
      "TVU:123"
   ],
   "phones":[
      "370665566",
      "3706324231"
   ]
}
```

This is output from server. I need to get seperate values but I don't know how to do it.

Tried this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                builder.append(line).append("\n");
}

JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(builder.toString());              
JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(tokener);
Log.e("IO-OUTPUT", builder.toString());  //prints json output
Log.e("finalResult (1)", finalResult.getString(1));
```

But I get ant exception:

```
W/System.err(31249): org.json.JSONException: Value {"blockedStatus":true,"cars":["RAW"],"phones":["65431"]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Is there another way to get values? Because calculating symbols and getting values from it will be too hard

Comment: There are some really nice libraries for working with JSON that make your life a lot easier, especially when your domain model changes and you need to update your JSON accordingly. Take a look at Gson or Jackson.

Comment: Gson is really a great work to save time.

Comment: Check out json-io, a relatively small library ~100K that has no other dependencies other than the JDK.  It is popular with Android developers.  https://github.com/jdereg/json-io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(builder.toString());              
JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(tokener);
```

to

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(builder.toString());              
JSONArray carsResult = jsonObject.getJSONArray("cars");
JSONArray phoneResult = jsonObject.getJSONArray("phones");
```

your string rapresent a `JSONObject` which contains two `JSONArray`'s, `cars` and `phones`, and a pair key/value `blockedStatus` .

Also, if you read the logcat, it says:

```
type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

You can not convert a `JSONObject` to a `JSONArray`, which means the you have a `JSONObject`

Comment: Thank you very much for saving my time! Just added catch clause and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
request.setURI(new URI(url));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
InputStream ips  = response.getEntity().getContent();
responseString = response.toString();
responseString = intputStreamToStringConvertor(ips);
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(responseString);
Boolean status = object.getBoolean("blockedStatus");
JsonArray cars = object.getJSONArray("cars");
JsonArray phones = object.getJSONArray("phones");
```